# What is the definition of piecewise continuous function in the context of a Laplace transformations?

Tags: laplace-transform

I have been taught the definition of PWC function for a finite interval where there will be a finite number of discontinuities. But in the context of Laplace transformations, for checking sufficient conditions for the existence of a transformations but we weren't given a new definition for an infinite intervals [0,\infty]. I think the definition might be extended by saying the discontinuities are countably infinite ? I couldn't find it in my textbook or online ( I might have missed it ).

Another question I had was should the limit of the function exist at both the endpoints or just 0 ?

Comment: A standard sufficient condition for the existence of the Laplace transform is given with proof in the accepted answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/948352/the-existence-of-the-laplace-transform). I don't see how piecewise continuity (or even continuity) could be a sufficient condition.

Comment: I am asking for the definition of a PWC function for an infinite interval. I know that there are 2 sufficient conditions (the other one being the function should be of exponential order) for the existence of a Laplace transform. By sufficient, what I mean is that if these 2 conditions are true the Laplace will exist as in these are sufficient for the existence of a Laplace but not necessary.

Comment: So we agree that a Laplace transform exists when the function is Lebesge measurable, integrable on finite intervals, and grows at most of exponential order. Apart from that: if you want to know (for whatever reason) what a piecewise continuous function on $[0,+\infty)$ is see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1950525/piecewise-continuity-with-countably-infinite-discontinuities).

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you !